# Text File I/O arraylist error is occuring

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TextFile
{
          public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        PrintWriter myWriter = new PrintWriter(args[0]);
        ArrayList<TextFile> myNums = new ArrayList<TextFile>(); 
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double sum = 0;
        double average;
        for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            FileReader myReader = new FileReader(args[i]);
            Scanner intScan = new Scanner(myReader);
            while (intScan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String textLine = intScan.nextLine();
                myWriter.println(textLine);
            }
            myReader.close();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + intScan[i];
            average = sum / args.length;
            if(myNums[i] > max)
            {
                max = intScan[i];
            }
            if(myNums[i] < min)
            {
                min = intScan[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of entries in the file is: " + args.length);
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The largest number is: " + max);
        System.out.println("The largest number is: " + min);

        myWriter.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I am attempting to write a program where I pull grades from a file within the class folder that I am using and create an Array List that will count the number of entries, give the sum of entries, average, max and min numbers. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `"What did I do wrong?"` -- For me, it's hard to say. What error or problem are you seeing? Does your code compile? If not, please show the full error message that the compiler is giving to you. Are you getting an exception? If so, show the full stacktrace and let us know the line that throws it. Are you seeing a behavioral problem? If so, tell us about the expected vs. the observed behaviors. Details matter.

Comment: What you did wrong was you failed to tell us what the actual problem was and didn't post a stack trace with the accompanying exception (if applicable).

Comment: Looking again at your code, you've got multiple errors, and this suggests that you're style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set up a `Scanner intScan`
and call it as an array variable `intScan[i]` 
Same thing with your ArrayList myNums

What you are seeing are compile time errors from mistakes in your syntax. You are using ArrayList and Scanner as if they are array objects... which they are not.

Read this:
[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html),
[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

giving an object type of TextFile to your ArrayList does not make any sense.